# Why are my low-poly models rendering smoothly?

Tags: rendering

Sorry about the probably silly question, in advance.
This is my first time using blender, and I want to get into low-poly stuff, which has been great so far! [I managed to make a cat and that went pretty well.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KStkT.png)

I thought I'd make some trees next. However! Everything was going well until I rendered the models. The "rendered" viewport shading mode brought the result I was looking for (below).
[image: poly result]

Yet, when I properly rendered the models, they appeared rounded.
[image: round result]

Did I click something accidentally? Thank you so much!

Comment: Remove subsurf modifier from the modifier tab or if u still not getting attach the file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you! Resolved, I somehow had my render subdivisions (?) set to 2.